# SKEmitterNode Crash

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

I'm trying to load an SKEmitterNode from an sks file and I keep getting this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', 
reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: 
cannot decode object of class (SKEditorScene)'
```

Code:

```
var explosion = SKEmitterNode.emitterNodeWithName("Explosion")

retval.addChild(explosion)
```

ExtensionMethod:

```
class func emitterNodeWithName(name: String) -> SKEmitterNode
{
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: "sks")!) as SKEmitterNode
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is due to a bug where XCode is treating the .sks file as a scene and corrupting it. It's fixed in XCode 6.1 Beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue, seems like a bug in the current beta.
Here is a workaround:

```
func particleEmitterWithName(name : NSString) -> SKEmitterNode?
{
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: "sks")

    var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
    var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

    archiver.setClass(SKEmitterNode.self, forClassName: "SKEditorScene")
    let node = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as SKEmitterNode?
    archiver.finishDecoding()
    return node
}
```

Comment: This answer is brilliant. The `setClass` function seems to be unavoidable if you try to pass an archived object from an iOS app to its Apple Watch extension counterpart. Even if the same custom class is compiled for both the iOS app and the extension, it doesn't get the exact same name in the two binaries, and I had to adjust its name in the Apple Watch extension using this answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the crash occured after changing some attributes in the Particle Emitter Editor. So you can also edit the attributes in code or in Editor in Xcode 5 to avoid crash. Apparently the Editor in Xcode 6 is corrupting the file.